# AVD manager does not launch

Tags: android

I tried to open AVD Manager.exe and console flashes up and it doesn't start. I tried deleting the "Cache" and "AVD" folders inside C:\Users(Username).Android folder. Even it didn't help.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it from Eclipse with ADT plugin

> In Eclipse: select Window > AVD Manager, or click the AVD Manager icon
>   in the Eclipse toolbar.